# Specify platform when building a docker container via Docker SDK for Python

Tags: python, docker, sdk, docker-image

I'm trying to build an Alpine-based NGINX Docker image on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (64 bit).

Since I also have an older Raspberry Py 3 which is running on Raspbian (32 bit), I want that image to be a 32 bit version, which is why I specify `FROM arm32v7/alpine:3.13` in the Dockerfile.

I trigger the build via the SDK by calling

```py
stream = client.api.build(path=dockerfile_dir,
                          dockerfile='Dockerfile-Lastbuild',
                          tag=config['tag'],
                          labels=config['labels'],
                          platform='linux/arm/v7', # <- Ignored?
                          rm=True)
```

Then I'm getting the warning

> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/arm) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

I thought that by adding the argument `platform='linux/arm/v7'`, as specified [in the documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.build):

> platform (str) – Platform in the format os[/arch[/variant]].

, I would be instructing Docker  that I am requesting a specific platform.

When I just specify `FROM alpine:3.13` I'm getting the same warnings.

Only when I specify `FROM arm64v8/alpine:3.13` the warnings disappear, but I assume that the resulting image is no longer compatible with `arm32v7`, which would be a requirement to run on the Raspberry Pi 3 (32 bit).

I haven't tried it manually via the console, which is something I will do next, but what exactly is the purpose of that `platform` argument then?

---

I noticed that if I remove the `platform` argument, and then use `FROM alpine:3.13` the warnings disappear. So I assume that this argument only has effect on which variant of the Alpine image is pulled by default.

This does not explain what is meant by `and no specific platform was requested`.